# grep for complete word doesn't work when the word contains a dash

Tags: regex, string, grep

I am `grep`ing for a whole word using `-w` flag and it isn't working correctly. I am assuming it's because the source words contain a "dash" ("-") character:

```
echo "sdf-a" > /tmp/grep.txt
~/Developer : cat /tmp/grep.txt 
sdf-a
```

should not return anything:

```
cat /tmp/grep.txt | grep -w a
sdf-a <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< BAD
```

I've also tried with the "\" option:

```
cat /tmp/grep.txt | grep  "\<a\>"
sdf-a << Should not return it
```

When I remove the dash from the source word:

```
~/Developer/ : echo "sdfa" > /tmp/grep.txt
~/Developer/ : cat /tmp/grep.txt | grep  "\<a\>" // nothing returned as expected
~/Developer/ : cat /tmp/grep.txt | grep -w a // nothing returned as expected
```

Comment: Technically speaking, `-` is not a word characters, so `a` is a whole word in `sdf-a`.

Comment: what is the workaroudn then? I want to search for complete matches in strings containing dashes

Comment: Maybe `grep -P "(?<!-)\ba\b(?!-)"`

Comment: Did it work for you? Another idea - `grep -E "(^|[^-])\ba\b($|[^-])"`

Comment: I need to check. Also the words can have multiple dashes

Comment: I just am not sure if you need to get the whole lines or just matches (`-o` option will be necessary)

Comment: whole line is fine

Comment: You don't need to cat the file and pipe `|` it to grep.  Grep will open the file for you. e.g. `grep -w a /tmp/grep.txt.`

Comment: To go even further, while you're testing (assuming you are using a recent version of bash) you can use: `grep -w a <<< "sdf-a"`.

Comment: So, how are things going? Did you find any edge cases to deal with?

Comment: It was complicated to do properly so I created a small script

Comment: @AvnerBarr: Then please post it.

Answer (score 0):

Resorted to a small ruby routine (for my purposes) that will match with multiple dashes:

```
def grep(file,val)
    res = []
    text = File.open(file).read
    text.each_line { |l|
      if l.include?(val)
        res.push(l)
      end
    }
    if res.count == 0
      return nil
    end
    return res
  end
```

Comment: I am not sure how this solves the issue stated in OP.

Comment: grep -w "something" file.txt would have returned "something-with-dashes" . Which is what I *don't* want. This small routine would return only complete word matches